# Dynamic Route Matching -- how to bind an object key that contains a space?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to use [Vue Router dynamic route matchin](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)g and have an object key of `NAS ID` with a space.

How would I bind that to the router path?

```
{ 
    path: '/:NAS ID',
    component: DataDetail
  }
```

The above path value gives me an error in console:

```
Expected "NAS" to be defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Route matching is powered by https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp .  You can use their documentation to look for a similar case.

My first guess would be to try escaping the space: `path: '/:NAS\ ID'`